# Cannot login to website by using JSOUP with x-www-form-urlencoded parameters

Tags: java, jsoup

How can I implement the following request by using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/)?

> POST /login/user HTTP/1.1
>   Host: url.publishedprices.co.il
>   Cache-Control: no-cache 
>   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> username=readonly&password=123456&csrftoken=wohewqfDrcK2JMK5w7BKw4jCuMOiARnDg01Rw4VZdQ%3D%3D

I've tried the following code but it doesn't work, I get an error from a site that

> Did not receive expected security token

I'm using this code:

```
Document welcomePage = Jsoup.connect("https://url.publishedprices.co.il/login").get();
Element inputHidden = welcomePage.getElementById("csrftoken");


String securityTokenKey = inputHidden.attr("name");
String securityTokenValue = inputHidden.attr("value");

Connection.Response res2 = Jsoup.connect("https://url.publishedprices.co.il/login/user")
        .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
        .data("username", "readonly")
        .data("password", "123456")
        .data(securityTokenKey, securityTokenValue)
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

System.out.println(res2.body());
Map<String, String> loginCookies = res2.cookies();
```

I know that when I use `x-www-form-urlencoded` I need to encode it within URL but supposed that when I set correct header JSOUP do it for me, am I wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the cookie (which contains the session with the secret token), so that the CSRF protection on server side will be able to compare the tokens and grant you access.

```
Connection.Response res1 = Jsoup.connect("https://url.publishedprices.co.il/login").method(Method.GET).execute();
        Document welcomePage = res1.parse();
        Map welcomCookies = res1.cookies();
        Element inputHidden = welcomePage.getElementById("csrftoken");


        String securityTokenKey = inputHidden.attr("name");
        String securityTokenValue = inputHidden.attr("value");

        Connection.Response res2 = Jsoup.connect("https://url.publishedprices.co.il/login/user")
                .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                .data("username", "readonly")
                .data("password", "123456")
                .data(securityTokenKey, securityTokenValue)
                .cookies(welcomCookies)
                .method(Method.POST)
                .execute();

        System.out.println(res2.body());
```