# Login to secure website with redirects Java / Jsoup

Tags: java, web, automation, jsoup

How do I go about reading and locating where I need to input login information in jsoup in order to access the web on a VPN?
I'm interested in both an explanation of the steps/topics involved as well as the programming methodology with java (basically how to code this in java using jsoup).
*Note: with all the redirects, I have a hard time understanding what is happening and how/when/where to code in a jsoup-login.*

Here's my workflow so far:

I have a target page, like the one below

```
[debug] status code 302 : https://centrale.landingnetwork.com/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/home/
```

Corresponding Headers:

```
{Server=Server, Date=Fri, 02 Mar 2018 04:36:49 GMT, Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Connection=keep-alive, x-REQUESTNAME-id-1=ZZZAAA3YYYBBB9CCC999, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-REQUESTNAME-id-2=123aaaWww1111iiiiix7777yyyzzzqqqhhhiiiE/wPUx/IaHiw6hfs7Y7/Gwa1X0, Location=https://centrale.landingnetwork.com/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/signin/gi-signin.html/123-1234567-1234567?ie=UTF8&landat=%2Fgp%2Fstores%2Fwww.landingnetwork.com%2Fgp%2Fhome%2F123-1234567-1234567&ort=1122334455.98765&rrt=1112223334.12121, Vary=Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, Content-Encoding=gzip, Set-cookie=session-id-scsus=123-1234567-1234567; path=/; domain=.landingnetwork.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 00:00:01 GMT}
```

When I navigate to this URL in java/jsoup, I get all kinds of redirects. Here's the trail of my redirects: (in order of which comes next)

```
[debug] status code 302 : https://centrale.landingnetwork.com/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/signin/gi-signin.html/123-1234567-1234567?ie=UTF8&landat=%2Fgp%2Fstores%2Fwww.landingnetwork.com%2Fgp%2Fhome%2F123-1234567-1234567&ort=1122334455.98765&rrt=1112223334.12121
```

Corresponding Headers:

```
{Server=Server, Date=Fri, 02 Mar 2018 04:36:49 GMT, Content-Type=text/html; charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Connection=keep-alive, x-REQUESTNAME-id-1=ZZZAAA3YYYBBB9CCC999, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-REQUESTNAME-id-2=123aaaWww1111iiiiix7777yyyzzzqqqhhhiiiEwwPwwwIaHiw6hfs7Y7vvva1X0, Location=https://wa.secureallnetwork.com/login?clienteId=Centrale-prod-wa&nonce=867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:53099&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcentrale.landingnetwork.com%3A443%2Fgp%2Fstores%2Fwww.landingnetwork.com%2Fgp%2Fsignin%2Fgi-landat.html%2F123-1234567-1234567%3Flandat%3D%2Fgp%2Fstores%2Fwww.landingnetwork.com%2Fgp%2Fhome%2F123-1234567-1234567&ort=1122334455.98765&rrt=1112223334.12121, Vary=Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, Content-Encoding=gzip, Set-cookie=session-id-scsus=123-1234567-1234567; path=/; domain=.landingnetwork.com; expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 00:00:01 GMT}
```

And the next link in the trail of links:

```
[debug] status code 200 : https://wa.secureallnetwork.com/login?clienteId=Centrale-prod-wa&nonce=867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:53099&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcentrale.landingnetwork.com%3A443%2Fgp%2Fstores%2Fwww.landingnetwork.com%2Fgp%2Fsignin%2Fgi-landat.html%2F123-1234567-1234567%3Flandat%3D%2Fgp%2Fstores%2Fwww.landingnetwork.com%2Fgp%2Fhome%2F123-1234567-1234567&ort=1122334455.98765&rrt=1112223334.12121
```

Corresponding Headers:

```
{Server=Server, Date=Fri, 02 Mar 2018 04:36:50 GMT, Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Connection=keep-alive, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload, Content-Language=en-US, Content-Encoding=gzip, Vary=Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, Set-Cookie=session-id=123-1234567-1234567; Domain=.landingnetwork.com; Expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT; Path=/}
```

And the next link in the trail of links:

```
[debug] status code 200 : https://wa.secureallnetwork.com/login?sif_profile=gi_profile_1&clienteId=Centrale-prod-wa&nonce=867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:53099&redirect_uri=https://centrale.landingnetwork.com:443/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/signin/gi-landat.html/123-1234567-1234567?landat=/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/home/123-1234567-1234567
```

Corresponding Headers:

```
{Server=Server, Date=Fri, 02 Mar 2018 04:36:50 GMT, Content-Type=text/html;charset=UTF-8, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, Connection=keep-alive, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload, Content-Language=en-US, Content-Encoding=gzip, Vary=Accept-Encoding,User-Agent, Set-Cookie=ubid-main=123-1234567-1234567; Domain=.landingnetwork.com; Expires=Tue, 01-Jan-2036 08:00:01 GMT; Path=/}
```

edit: determining that the nonce values didn't need to be the exact ones shown, I edited them a generic value. Same idea for the `&rrt=` and the `&ort=` values. (If these play a significance to my task, please explain).

edit2: added in the respective headers to each link.

edit2: also, here is the value of the login form's `action=` value.

```
/login?sif_profile=gi_profile_1&clientId=Centrale-prod-na&nonce=867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:5309:867:53099&redirect_uri=https://centrale.landingnetwork.com:443/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/signin/gi-landat.html/123-1234567-1234567?landat=/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/home/123-1234567-1234567
```

Now, I don't have a super big background in networking, but I can definitely follow along if explained well/thoroughly.

My issue: when I go through redirects, I don't know why my form posting code of my username / password doesn't work.

edit3: Here are the request headers information during navigation as seen in chrome network tab:

```
POST /gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/handlers/remote-view.html HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 6013
Accept: */*
Cookie: loc-main=en_US; x-xUid-uid=along141charactersofnonsesnsegoeshere; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=123-1234567-1234567; ubid-main=987-6543210-1234567; csrf=-2233445566; x-main="rr@DDhhzzqqeerrttyyuuiiooppkk@77"; at-main=alonglineof417charactersgoeshere; sess-at-main="mm2m/PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPooooooooooooooooooo="; sst-main=alonglineof200somecharactersgoeshere; session-id-scsus=123-1234567-1234567; session-id-time-scsus=2082758401l; ubid-scsus=987-6543210-1234567; session-token-scsus=hereisacoollineof256characters; skin=noskin; session-token="sessiontokenof268charactersgoeshere"; sidna-p=43charactershere; gidna-p=amonster1607charactershere; cscscs-p=::777::D11vvvvZZZZZZZZZzzzMMMMwwwwwjjjjjeeeeeeevvvvvvbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmm77777777aaaaaa+w/wwwwwww==; csm-hit=222.33|1234567891011
```

---

```
POST /gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/telephony/handlers/get-due-followup HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 373
Accept: */*
Cookie: loc-main=en_US; x-xUid-uid=along141charactersofnonsesnsegoeshere; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=123-1234567-1234567; ubid-main=987-6543210-1234567; csrf=-2233445566; x-main="rr@DDhhzzqqeerrttyyuuiiooppkk@77"; at-main=alonglineof417charactersgoeshere; sess-at-main="mm2m/PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPooooooooooooooooooo="; sst-main=alonglineof200somecharactersgoeshere; session-id-scsus=123-1234567-1234567; session-id-time-scsus=2082758401l; ubid-scsus=987-6543210-1234567; session-token-scsus=hereisacoollineof256characters; skin=noskin; session-token="sessiontokenof268charactersgoeshere"; sidna-p=43charactershere; gidna-p=amonster1607charactershere; cscscs-p=::777::D11vvvvZZZZZZZZZzzzMMMMwwwwwjjjjjeeeeeeevvvvvvbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmm77777777aaaaaa+w/wwwwwww==; csm-hit=222.33|1234567891011
```

---

```
GET /taw/static/connect-csm.js?_=hereis13numbers HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Cookie: loc-main=en_US; x-xUid-uid=along141charactersofnonsesnsegoeshere; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=123-1234567-1234567; ubid-main=987-6543210-1234567; csrf=-2233445566; x-main="rr@DDhhzzqqeerrttyyuuiiooppkk@77"; at-main=alonglineof417charactersgoeshere; sess-at-main="mm2m/PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPooooooooooooooooooo="; sst-main=alonglineof200somecharactersgoeshere; session-id-scsus=123-1234567-1234567; session-id-time-scsus=2082758401l; ubid-scsus=987-6543210-1234567; session-token-scsus=hereisacoollineof256characters; skin=noskin; session-token="sessiontokenof268charactersgoeshere"; sidna-p=43charactershere; gidna-p=amonster1607charactershere; cscscs-p=::777::D11vvvvZZZZZZZZZzzzMMMMwwwwwjjjjjeeeeeeevvvvvvbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmm77777777aaaaaa+w/wwwwwww==; csm-hit=222.33|1234567891011
```

---

```
GET /taw/static/secureall-conduit.js?_=hereis13numbers HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Cookie: loc-main=en_US; x-xUid-uid=along141charactersofnonsesnsegoeshere; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=123-1234567-1234567; ubid-main=987-6543210-1234567; csrf=-2233445566; x-main="rr@DDhhzzqqeerrttyyuuiiooppkk@77"; at-main=alonglineof417charactersgoeshere; sess-at-main="mm2m/PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPooooooooooooooooooo="; sst-main=alonglineof200somecharactersgoeshere; session-id-scsus=123-1234567-1234567; session-id-time-scsus=2082758401l; ubid-scsus=987-6543210-1234567; session-token-scsus=hereisacoollineof256characters; skin=noskin; session-token="sessiontokenof268charactersgoeshere"; sidna-p=43charactershere; gidna-p=amonster1607charactershere; cscscs-p=::777::D11vvvvZZZZZZZZZzzzMMMMwwwwwjjjjjeeeeeeevvvvvvbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmm77777777aaaaaa+w/wwwwwww==; csm-hit=222.33|1234567891011
```

---

```
GET /taw/get-csm-parameters HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Cookie: loc-main=en_US; x-xUid-uid=along141charactersofnonsesnsegoeshere; session-id-time=2082787201l; session-id=123-1234567-1234567; ubid-main=987-6543210-1234567; csrf=-2233445566; x-main="rr@DDhhzzqqeerrttyyuuiiooppkk@77"; at-main=alonglineof417charactersgoeshere; sess-at-main="mm2m/PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPooooooooooooooooooo="; sst-main=alonglineof200somecharactersgoeshere; session-id-scsus=123-1234567-1234567; session-id-time-scsus=2082758401l; ubid-scsus=987-6543210-1234567; session-token-scsus=hereisacoollineof256characters; skin=noskin; session-token="sessiontokenof268charactersgoeshere"; sidna-p=43charactershere; gidna-p=amonster1607charactershere; cscscs-p=::777::D11vvvvZZZZZZZZZzzzMMMMwwwwwjjjjjeeeeeeevvvvvvbbbbbbbbbbmmmmmm77777777aaaaaa+w/wwwwwww==; csm-hit=222.33|1234567891011
```

Here's my code so far, (two classes);

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.UncheckedIOException;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class App {
    public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0";
    public static final String LOGIN_FORM_URL = "https://centrale.landingnetwork.com/gp/stores/www.landingnetwork.com/gp/home/";
    public static final String USERNAME = "myusername";  
    public static final String PASSWORD = "mupassword";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebCrawler wc = new WebCrawler();

        // # Go to login page and grab cookies sent by server
        Connection.Response loginForm = wc.crawl(LOGIN_FORM_URL);

        // this is the document containing response html
        Document loginDoc = loginForm.parse();

        // save the cookies to be passed on to next request
        HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>(loginForm.cookies());  

        // # Prepare login credentials
        String authToken = loginDoc.select("form").attr("class", "a-spacing-micro").first().attr("action");

        HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();
        formData.put("usernameInputField", USERNAME);
        formData.put("passwordInputField", PASSWORD);

        Connection.Response homePage = wc.crawl("https://wa.secureallnetwork.com" + authToken, cookies, formData, Connection.Method.POST, true);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.Connection.Response;

public class WebCrawler {
    public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0";

    public Connection.Response crawl(String URL) throws IOException {
        Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent(USER_AGENT).followRedirects(false).execute();
        if (response.hasHeader("location")) {
            String redirectUrl = response.header("location");
            return crawl(redirectUrl);
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }

    public Connection.Response crawl(String URL, HashMap<String, String> cooks, HashMap<String, String> dat, Connection.Method m, boolean follow) throws IOException {
        Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent(USER_AGENT).cookies(cooks).data(dat).followRedirects(follow).method(m).execute();

        if (response.hasHeader("location")) {
            String redirectUrl = response.header("location");
            return crawl(redirectUrl);
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

When I print out the headers, they seem relatively straight forward, the only things that might stand out to me are, `'X-REQUEST-ID1'`/`'X-REQUEST-ID2'` headers, set cookie session id, and a location. But I'm sure that's not where I'm having my main troubles at - I think it's more where I attempt to interact with the data over multiple web pages with jsoup.

**To reiterate my question**: How can I login pragmatically with java/jsoup to my website? A thorough explanation with details/examples/final code would be a glorious lesson if somebody would be willing to take the time!

Cheers

Comment: I can't follow the URLs in question, so can't check properly, but the only obviously missing bit looks like the Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded in the headers.  Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406264/cannot-login-to-website-by-using-jsoup-with-x-www-form-urlencoded-parameters) for a similar example.

Comment: The URLs are changed to hello-world examples. This is due to the actual links not being publicly available. I'll edit into the original post what the headers look like for each page. Also, thanks for the similar example, I will look into it.

Comment: updated the question with the headers and the login form's action= value.

Comment: What you asking is for someone to reverse engineer a login flow of a web site they have no access to.

Comment: It sounds like the right thing to focus on headers here.  Those look like the response headers in the question now?  (e.g. the Location for the 302/Redirect).  Normally adding the right request headers to the Jsoup.connect() (maybe gleaned from the F12/Network tab in Chrome or Firefox) makes all the difference.  E.g. I've known a server fail to respond due to a missing Accept-Language.

Comment: Selenium might be more applicable than jsoup in this situation

Comment: added an 'edit3:' to show the added chrome view of the network request headers - also, trying to use jsoup here in order to gain the knowledge required for this task. If Selenium is more applicable, is there an answer and informational sources to provide insight to this task/question?